# Binding Style to a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a TextBox like the following:

```
<TextBox 
 Name="TxtBackupPath" 
 Grid.Column="0"
 Grid.Row="0"
 Height="Auto" 
 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
 Style="{Binding Path=BackupPathStyle}" 
 Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}"
 Text="{Binding Path=BackupPath, Mode=TwoWay}" 
 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
 AcceptsReturn="True"
 Margin="3,3" 
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
 />
```

In Code I can set the ForegroundColor like the following without errors:

```
Brush _Red = Brushes.Red;
backupDirectory.ForegroundColor = _Red;
```

backupDirectory is the dataSource that is tied to the UI. I am trying to use MVVM as a pattern to set UI elements through Properties in code. When I try to use a Style like:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Goldenrod));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Aqua));
backupDirectory.BackupPathStyle = style;
```

I get the "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." error. I don't understand why Style and Foreground reacts differently when set from code.

Is it possible to set the Style of a TextBox through a property? What is the simplest approach to this using MVVM?

Comment: How does backupDirectory related to TextBox?  Is it the DataContext of the control/window that the TextBox is on?  Where are you setting ForegroundColor directly compared to the BackupPathStyle?  This error generally means that you're trying to update a UI element from anything other than the main UI thread, so you'd have to invoke the call back to the UI thread.

Comment: In MVVM, you don't set things like colors in ViewModel. You do it purely in View, preferably with only XAML.

Comment: Color is based on condition of underlying data. As the data is processed I need to set the color of the text box holding the data in the view. Could not find a simple way of doing this in MVVM so I could use some help there.

Comment: backupDirectory is the name of the ObservableCollection that I have loaded my model data into. Each time I set a property in this collection I fire off INotifyPropertyChanged to update the UI. Like I said, it works fine when setting Foreground but gives me the error when setting Style and this is perplexing.

Comment: I Added the following DataTrigger to the TextBox and used a ProgressBar property to drive the TextBox Style. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! : <TextBox.Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
<Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DirectoryProgress}" Value="0">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DirectoryProgress}" Value="100">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGoldenrod" />
</DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</TextBox.Style>

Answer (score 0):

> I get the "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." error. I don't understand why Style and Foreground reacts differently when set from code.

Such properties must be set from the (one and only) UI thread -- your code is clearly running on a background thread. You can schedule code to be executed on the UI thread like so:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MyControl.Style = new Style());
```

That said, including at least parts of `backupDirectory` (especially the property you're setting) in the OP would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make some guesses.

1. Your code is running in another thread.
2. `Brush _Red = Brushes.Red; backupDirectory.ForegroundColor = _Red;` does not instantiate any new objects; `Brushes.Red` is a static property that has been instantiated by UI thread, while you are just assigning the reference of that pre-instantiated object to the `ForegroundColor` property.
3. `Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));` is obviously instantiating a new instance of `Style` class. Provided `point 1` is correct, then this object is not created on UI thread.